# How to set environment in crontab for php imagick?

Tags: php, imagemagick, cron, imagick

I want to execute my code, resizing image using php imagick function in  cron job. But it doesn't work, because I don't know how to set imagemagick's environment in crontab correctly.

My OS is ubuntu 14.04, PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.7 (cli)

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=~/bin:/usr/bin/:/bin
HOME=/
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to set things up inside your crontab, just execute a simple script from cron that sets things up for you.

So, in your crontab

```
 0 0 * * * /usr/local/bin/resize_it
```

and then create your script with

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin
...
php ...
```

and save it as `/usr/local/bin/resize_it` and make it executable with

```
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/resize_it
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mark Setchell. You solved my problem. Today I've a time to see my code. I set the environment path correctly like this: #!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/bin/convert
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
HOME=/root